# Cannot create file and use filepath in Modelcheckpoint

Tags: keras

I am following this super nice tutorial here https://dashee87.github.io/data%20science/deep%20learning/python/another-keras-tutorial-for-neural-network-beginners/.

However, I can't use the filepath in Modelcheckpoint correctly.

```
filepath="C:/Users/Thomas01/Documents/pimaindiansdiabetescsv/nnweights- 
{epoch:02d}.hdf5"
checkpoint = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_acc', 
verbose=0, save_weights_only=False, save_best_only=False, mode='max')
```

[...]

```
temp_test_model.load_weights("C:/Users/Thomas01/Documents/pimaindiansdiabetescsv/nnweights-%02d.hdf5" % i)
```

[...]

I get :

OSError: Unable to open file (unable to open file: name = 'C:/Users/Thomas01/Documents/pimaindiansdiabetescsv/nnweights-00.hdf5', errno = 2, error message = 'No such file or directory', flags = 0, o_flags = 0)

Tried to use a raw string (but I think I lose the argument specifier ?) , or \, but none work.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says (`No such file or directory`) that the file path to the model checkpoint cannot be found so the directory will not be opened. You need to create a folder like `pimaindiansdiabetescsv` in this location:`C:/Users/Thomas01/Documents/`.

Comment: I made this folder myself. The path exists

Comment: @Clipper, I think you can refer to this solution.[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48951166/pandas-wont-open-hdf5-files-on-a-usb-drive-under-windows][1]

Answer (score 0):

Set `verbose=1` to see where it saves

```
checkpoint = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_weights_only=False, save_best_only=False, mode='max') 

# Epoch 00001: val_acc improved from -inf to 0.53781, saving model to /yourpath/yourpath
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it's because of Windows backslashes, if you wanna save the whole model and you don't put a `/` at the end of the checkpoint directory path, keras will append a `\`, but a single `\` will break things on Windows from Python.

First, you're trying to save a whole model, so don't specify `.hdf5` in the filepath.

Second, append a `/` at the end.

```
dir_path="C:/Users/Thomas01/Documents/pimaindiansdiabetescsv/nnweights- 
{epoch:02d}/"
checkpoint = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(dir_path, monitor='val_acc', 
verbose=0, save_weights_only=False, save_best_only=False, mode='max')
```

If you only want to save the weights, then your original path will work, but you need to change the parameter `save_weights_only` to True.