# Model Checkpoint doesn't create a directory

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I was learning about model saving in Keras, and it seems like my model checkpoint object doesn't create the specified directory. Here is the code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
checkpoint_5000_path = \
    'model_checkpoints_5000/checkpoint_{epoch:02d}_{batch:04d}'
checkpoint_5000 = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_5000_path,
                                  save_freq=5000,
                                  save_weights_only=True,
                                  verbose=2)
model = get_new_model()
model.fit(x_train,y_train,epochs=10,validation_split=0.15,callbacks=[checkpoint_5000],verbose=2)
```

When I try to access the directory,

```
! ls -lh model_checkpoints_5000
```

this error shows up.

```
ls: cannot access 'model_checkpoints_5000': No such file or directory
```

What could be the reason for this?
Btw I am not doing this on my local machine. I use Google Colab.

Comment: If you're getting the same error even though you've created the folder, check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/76142060/5185763

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ModelCheckpoint` in keras does not create any directory. You have to create the folder `model_checkpoints_5000` before training the model, otherwise it will fail to save the model after finishing an epoch returning an error like this:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Failed to create a directory: model_checkpoints_5000/XXX; No such file or directory
```